# Is there an equivalent to #if that can evaluate template arguments?

Tags: c++, templates, macros

The `#if` preprocessor directive evaluates expression of "constants" known to the preprocessor. Is there anything similar that can evaluate expressions on template arguments?

In practice, I have something like this:

```
template<int i>    
class Elem{ /*...*/};

#ifndef NUM_ELEM
#define NUM_ELEM 2 
#endif    

class MyClass
{

    #if NUM_ELEM >= 1
        Elem<1> e_1;
    #endif
    #if NUM_ELEM >= 2
        Elem<2> e_2;
    #endif
    #if NUM_ELEM >= 3
        Elem<3> e_3;
    #endif

    /*...*/
}
```

But I'd really like to make MyClass into a template itself:

```
template<int num_elem>
MyClass{

    #if num_elem >= 1 //but #if can't understand num_elem
        Elem<1> e_1;
    #endif
    #if num_elem >= 2
        Elem<2> e_2;
    #endif
    #if num_elem >= 3
        Elem<3> e_3;
    #endif 

    /*...*/
};
```

Comment: std::conditional? To elaborate you could to something like `std::conditional_t<num_elem >= 1, Elem<1>, void>`. How you do this recursively is another thing.

Comment: @Blazo It cannot be used to eliminate member from class completely. In your case you will get a compiler error, because you are trying to create an instance of type `void`

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot Looks like it's time for me to go to bed. That's what I get for not sleeping for more than 20 hours (energy drinks really are something else).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The short answer is no, but if you're willing to change your requirements a little, you could do something like:

```
// A run of elements - Elem<n>, ..., Elem<2>, Elem<1>
template <int n> class NumElems
{
    template <int u, int v> friend class ElemGetter;

    NumElems<n-1> before;

    public:
    Elem<n> e;

    // method to retrieve an element by number
    template <int m> Elem<m> &getElem();
};

// helper class to retrieve an element.
//  'n' is the element number to retrieve
//  'm' is the number of elements
// by default, ElemGetter<n,m> defers to ElemGetter<n,m-1>.
template <int n, int m> class ElemGetter
{
    public:
    static Elem<n> &getElem(NumElems<m> &numElems)
    {
        return ElemGetter<n,m-1>::getElem(numElems.before);
    }
};

// specialisation of ElemGetter: if the element to get is the same as the
// number of elements (i.e. is the last element) then return it
// immediately.
template <int n> class ElemGetter<n,n>
{
    public:
    static Elem<n> &getElem(NumElems<n> &numElems)
    {
        return numElems.e;
    }
};

// get an element by number; defers to the ElemGetter helper.
template <int n> template <int m> Elem<m> &NumElems<n>::getElem()
{
    return ElemGetter<m,n>::getElem(*this);
}

template <> class NumElems<0>
{
};
```

...  then you can declare your Elem member set with:

```
NumElems<NUM_ELEM> elems;
```

And you can access them by using:

```
Elem<2> &e = elems.getElem<2>();
```

**Original proposed code**

The original code I proposed does not actually compile, but I'll include it here as it better demonstrates *intent* of the above:

```
// Original, doesn't compile - but it would be nice if it did :/
template <int n> class NumElems : private NumElems<n-1>
{
    Elem<n> e;

    template <int m> Elem<m> &getElem()
    {
        return NumElems<n-1>::getElem<m>();
    }

    template <> Elem<n> &getElem<n>()
    {
        return e;
    }
};

template <> class NumElems<0>
{
};
```

Unfortunately, C++ does not allow specialisation of member template functions in this way, though it's not clear (to me) why not - the code is definitely simpler without having to create a helper class, as in the working code above.

Comment: It might be a good case for private inheritace, unless you argue that `NumElems<3>` is-a `NumElems<2>`

Comment: @davmac thanks for the edit! I was a bit puzzled adapting it to my code.

Comment: @darius no problem, I've done another iteration which improves by avoiding inheritance also. Check the updated answer.

Comment: @Revolver_Ocelot you're right, and I've updated the original code that I posted accordingly. Unfortunately however I've since discovered that it did not compile, and I've had to rework my solution significantly. It now avoids inheritance altogether, which seems a better option.

Comment: Well, it is certainly better than recursive inheritance. You might make `e` private too, as `ElemGetter` is a friend. I was thinking about tuple-like approach with multiple private inheritance, but I do not trust myself to write code using template-pack correctly right away, and I do not have tools nor time to play with it right now.